# Using X-Frame-Options customHeaders - add multiple uri/domains to the web.config?

Tags: x-frame-options, custom-headers

Using X-Frame-Options customHeaders - add multiple uri/domains to the web.config?

. Is the following format to append multiple X-Frame-Options allowed in the web.config? And does it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible with X-frame-Options, instead you should use

```
<add name="Content-Security-Policy" value="frame-ancestors 'self' yourdomain1.com yourdomain2.com;"/>
```

Comment: rafeeq thanks for the update. but as you know the CSP 1 and CSP 2 version still don't support some of the browsers example : IE , 9 + and safari